# Fourier transform spherical system

Tags: python, fourier-analysis

I need to take the Fourier transform of a 3D function $h(r)=h(|r|)$ so that I can invert a convolution problem.

What is the best way to do this with Python?

I know the the FT is equivalent to a sine transform (see below) but I can't find a Python library that appears to let me do this integral. One issue I have is that although my sample points for $h(r)$ are regularly spaced they do not start from $r=0$ due to how they've been generated, does this cause any issues?.

$$\tilde{h}(k)=\frac{2}{k}\int_0^{\infty}rh(r)\sin(2\pi kr)dr$$

Comment: Have you checked [scipy.fftpack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fftpack.html)?